# How to configure inter-connected fields that would be reset every year

Tags: sales-cloud

I’m trying to create a few fields in an object in Salescloud that would depend on a date (Anniversary Date of 1st purchase).

•   A field “points” that would sums all purchases made during a year (from anniversary date of 1st purchase to a year -ie 15/01/2020 to 15/01/21, then from 16/01/2021 to 16/01/22 etc). 1€ would equal 1point (decimals not taken into account)

•   A field “status” that would be calculated upon rules : <300 -> Bronze ; ≥300 -> Silver ; purchase of a specific product (gold membership) -> Gold

- Those 2 fields would be inter connected (the field “points” would determine the field “status”
- The field “points” would be reset every year (at every anniversary date so that it can last for a year)
- The field "anniversary date of 1st purchase" would be as well to take into consideration the new year.

I read online that Apex class might be involved in this type of set-up but are there any other other options ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can theoretically do this with flows. One flow would set the Anniversary Date based on the oldest opportunity, one flow to update the amount sold on the account in the last year as "points", and a final flow that schedules itself for one year out to reset each account on their anniversary. The remaining piece is just a formula at that point. I would say that Apex would be slightly easier to build out this solution, but configuration-only is certainly possible.